# Why always include "v-else" template block?

Tags: vuejs2

I have two templates on components and one flag.

```
<template v-if="mainPage">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>1 page</h1>  
    </div>   
</template>
<template v-else>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>2 page</h1>
    </div>
</template>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            text : '',
            mainPage: true,
        }
    },
```

but default include second template. why?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when creating a vuejs you are only allowed one root element per component, so without the v-else part your component wouldnt work, unless you change template to div, and create one parent template:

If you don't want to use `v-if` you can just use `v-show` as:

```
<template v-show="mainPage">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>1 page</h1>  
    </div>   
</template>
<template>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>2 page</h1>
    </div>
</template>
```

This will not work for templates though. Because you can not have two templates in vuejs components